# How to remove double spacing from table

Tags: tables, spacing, line-spacing

The following code is making my tables within my document double spaced. Any suggestions on how to fix?

It is a multicolumn table with some specific formatting:[image]

```
\documentclass[poms,nonblindrev]{informs3}
\OneAndAHalfSpacedXII 

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{natbib}
 \bibpunct[, ]{(}{)}{,}{a}{}{,}
 \def\bibfont{\small}%
 \def\bibsep{\smallskipamount}%
 \def\bibhang{24pt}%
 \def\newblock{\ }%
 \def\BIBand{and}%

\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\TheoremsNumberedThrough    
\EquationsNumberedThrough    

%------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[htbp]
      \centering
      \caption{Comparison of RMSE within the Predict-Aggregate Approach}
      \scalebox{.8}{
        \begin{tabular}{lccccc}
        \hline
              & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Heteroskedastic} &       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Het. \& Selection} \\
              &       & vs Basic &       &       & vs Basic \\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textit{Bricks-and-Mortar Electronics Retailer Data}} \\
        Audio & 4.5   & -18.3\% &       & 4.0   & -28.7\% \\
        Auto Parts & 3.5   & -1.3\% &       & 3.5   & -1.9\% \\
        Cable & 3.3   & -0.3\% &       & 3.3   & 0.8\% \\
        Computer & 6.3   & -6.8\% &       & 6.2   & -9.0\% \\
        Imaging & 2.5   & -9.7\% &       & 2.5   & -9.1\% \\
        Mobile Phone & 3.5   & -6.5\% &       & 3.5   & -7.5\% \\
        Phone & 3.2   & -2.2\% &       & 3.3   & 0.2\% \\
        TV    & 3.4   & -10.1\% &       & 3.2   & -15.5\% \\
        TV Box & 9.1   & -5.6\% &       & 8.5   & -11.3\% \\
        \textbf{Simple Average} &       & \textbf{-6.8\%} &       &       & \textbf{-9.1\%} \\
        \textbf{Weighted Average} &       & \textbf{-6.4\%} &       &       & \textbf{-8.6\%} \\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textit{Online Jewelry Retailer Data}} \\
        Bracelets & 17.2  & 2.1\% &       & 16.4  & -2.7\% \\
        Earrings & 59.8  & -4.3\% &       & 58.9  & -5.7\% \\
        Necklaces & 65.7  & -0.9\% &       & 64.2  & -3.1\% \\
        Rings & 16.2  & -1.3\% &       & 15.4  & -6.4\% \\
        Other Accessories & 32.2  & -1.8\% &       & 32.2  & -2.0\% \\
        \textbf{Simple Average} &       & \textbf{-1.2\%} &       &       & \textbf{-4.0\%} \\
        \textbf{Weighted Average} &       & \textbf{-1.3\%} &       &       & \textbf{-4.3\%} \\
        \hline
        \end{tabular}}%
      \label{tab:addlabel}%
    \end{table}%

    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix by commenting out `\OneAndAHalfSpacedXII` in the very beginning. So: `%\OneAndAHalfSpacedXII` makes it a much tighter table.

Alternatively, you could change it to `\OneAndAHalfSpacedXI`, which also makes the spacing look tighter. These actually yield the same effect.